# Ways to find registration between images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am doing image registration

Are there other image-registration methods out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computing the regular cross-correlation through multiplying with the complex conjugate in the Fourier domain gives a nice peak that can be localized with sub-pixel precision. To find the location of the peak, fit a parabola to the 3x3 neighborhood of the largest value.

The [DIPimage](http://www.diplib.org) function `findshift` implements this method and a few other ones too. [The C++ source code is here](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/src/analysis/findshift.cpp) if you're interested in seeing how it's implemented.